# Tiny MCE Combo Box Strange Position

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, jquery, tinymce

i have used Tiny MCE and something wrong, the combo box list appear in strange position. Here's the link

http://103.imagebam.com/download/0q5oXQZf7-JsgaCeNjjkew/22248/222470402/Blur%20Image.png

How could I solved it?? Is it a bug?

I use latest Tiny MCE(3.5.8).

Comment: @Thariama it's just the way of me to explain, any problem?

Comment: ok, can i see your tinymce config?